# Filezilla Server gives wrong time

Tags: php, mysql, configuration-files, filezilla

My site hosting in **filezilla** server always saves wrong time in timestamp field in the mysql database..I checked my code in localhost it saves correct time clearly..Timestamp field query is below here

`$add_SQL = "insert into applicant (name, createdon) values ('$name', now())";`

Is there anything in the filezilla config affects it?
Please help me..Im hanging for 6 days.

Comment: did you check timezone of your server ?

Comment: FileZilla is an FTP server, that has nothing to with with your database.

Comment: filezilla server database is located in bangalore(300kms far from chennai)..But I am operating that from chennai..So I cannot change it in php config file...Then I am trying through php code...But couln't..when i print time it shows bangalore time(chennai +5minutes)..But when i insert a new data in database that created_on field(default:CURRENT TIMESTAMP), that saves a strange time(more than 1 hour difference from the correct time)...I tried "date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');"..but Its not come..What to do

Answer (score 0):

If you have admin rights on your database you can [change the timezone in the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql)

Otherwise you can do this with PHP. At the top of your script you should set the timezone, this will ensure that all date/time operations return values related to that timezone.

Then use PHP time() function in your query.

e.g.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
...
$add_SQL = "insert into applicant (name, createdon) values ('$name', ".time().")";
```

Ensure you provide a valid timezone: See [list of all possible timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)